# which version of flume should i use?

Tags: hadoop, flume, cloudera-cdh

I'm using CDH 4.7.0 and will be installing Flume to feed HDFS data.  I also downloaded Flume v1.4.0 from Apache (the same version that CDH comes with.  There seem to be 2 flume-ng-core files between the one that comes with CDH and the one from Apache.  There versions are 1.4.0 and 1.4.0-cdh4.7.0.  Should I be using 1.4.0-cdh4.7.0 or can I safely use 1.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

Flume 1.4.0 and Flume version 1.4.0-cdh4.7.0 are same but  1.4.0-cdh4.7.0 is compiled and tested with CDH4.7.0 therefore 1.4.0-cdh4.7.0 is risk free to use with CDH4.7.0.

Hence I recommend to use the cdh4.7.0 version of flume along with your CDH4.7.0 version.